# How to do auto increment serial number in flex data grid?

Tags: apache-flex

```
<mx:DataGridColumn labelFunction="sortSerial" headerText="Sl no" />
```

i had declared in Datacolumn section like this how to write auto increment serial number ?

Comment: I believe your coming at this from the wrong direction. A `DataGridColumn` is a visual represenation of existing data. How you populate `DataGrid.dataProvider` will determine how you auto generate your serials

Comment: I got an answer for my question

              private function sortSerial(oItem:Object,iCol:int):int
   {
   var iIndex:int = ac.getItemIndex(oItem) + 1;
    return int(iIndex);
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
  private function sortSerial(oItem:Object,iCol:int):int
        {
            var iIndex:int = ac.getItemIndex(oItem) + 1;
            return int(iIndex);
        }
```

Comment: SO generally frowns upon code only answers. Please consider updating your answer to explain how this solved your problem.